# std::regex in c++11 the preceding token is not quantifiable

Tags: regex, c++11, backreference

When using `std::regex` in c++11 I encounter some errors. Below I have shown the error

```
  {Unknown expression after the reported line}
due to unexpected exception with message:
  Invalid special open parenthesis.
```

I am trying to write a regular expression but I can't get it work for all the below mentioned cases

Here is my regex

```
\btmax\s*(\[(.*?((?:[^\[\]]+?|(\1))*)\]))
```

which when used with

```
tSunset = tmin[idx] + (tmax[idx] - tmin[idx]) * sin((M_PI * daylength[i])/(daylength[i] + 4.0));
```

correctly returns **idx**

However, when I used the expression

```
\bprec\s*(\[(.*?((?:[^\[\]]+?|(\1))*)\]))
```

with the following string

```
prec[season_idx[j] + i * 12];
```

I get **j**, though I expect to get **season_idx[j] + 1 * 12**.

I am using this with `std::regex` in c++11 so I am limited to ECMAScript. If I use regex compatible with PCRE like the following

```
\bprec\s*(\[(.*?((?:[^\[\]]+?|(?1))*)\]))
```

I get the correct response

`season_idx[j] + i * 12`

Comment: Why is this tagged 'javascript'?

Comment: Thanks, It should have been ecmascript

Comment: Understood - but your last edit put Javascript back on it again

Comment: ECMAScript does not support recursion. If you need it, use a pcre library.